# On some Windows 7, the .Net combobox does not appear even though the item is added

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, windows-7, windows-10

On some Windows 7 computers, the .Net combobox does not appear even though the item is added.  It works well on Windows 10. But after deploying, some Windows 7 32-bit PC seemed to add no items to the combobox.

Comment: Could you provide more details?

Comment: I made a wrong approach at all. It was identified as a problem caused by not running the Window Loaded Event but the Combobox problem.
However, on most PCs there is a report that Windows updates have been resolved.
I will think more about this issue.